# Some classes have no effect after adding Tailwind.css to a Vue.js project

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-cli, tailwind-css

I am trying to add Tailwind.css to a Vue.js project. There are a lot of resources on how to do this, most of them following the same path as [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5CUrUSCuO0). To make sure I was in the same conditions as in the video, I created a Vue app from scratch, using `vue-cli` with the default presets. After this step, I did the following :

- `npm install tailwind.css`
- create `src/styles/tailwind.css`
- adding the following to the css file:

```css
@tailwind base; 
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

- call `npx tailwind init` to create a `tailwind.config.js` file at the root of the project
- create `postcss.config.js` at the root of the project, and add the following to this file:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

- add a custom color to the `tailwind.config.js` file :

```js
module.exports = {   
  theme: {
    colors: {
      "awesome-color": "#56b890",
    },
    extend: {},
  },   
  variants: {},   
  plugins: [], 
};
```

- adding a simple `<p>` element to the `HelloWorld.vue` component generated by `vue-cli`
- trying to style it using `Tailwind` classes

Finally, here is the problem: I can apply some classes like `bg-awesome-color` or `text-xl` and have them render properly, but a lot other classes won't work.

For instance, removing those classes and trying instead `bg-black`, `bg-orange-500`, or `text-orange-500` has strictly no effect. Did I do something wrong? Would that be a problem of compatibility between Vue.js and Tailwind.css?

I do not know if this is related, but I also noticed that after adding Tailwind.css, the Vue logo that used to be centered in the original `vue-cli` template was now aligned left in the page.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 5):

If You want to keep original content, then you should put this inside "extend".

```
module.exports = { 
  theme: { 
    extend: {
      colors: { 
        "awesome-color": "#56b890", 
      }, 
    }
  }, 
  variants: {}, 
  plugins: [], 
};
```

Read more at: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration/

Comment: It's odd, I tried this months ago. Did not work. Came back my project and had overwritten all of my height properties.

used the extend and everything was fixed again.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer from a maintainer of Tailwind.css after posting an issue. I actually misplaced the `colors` object in `tailwind.config.js`, causing it to override all existing colors with mine, thus actually removing all the existing ones. Here is the correct way to add / override a color without removing all the original ones :

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "awesome-color": "#56b890",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, and I spent hours trying to understand why my custom styles weren't working, your error may be in the `postcss.config.js`, make sure when importing `tailwind.config.js` you are calling correctly, I leave a couple of examples:

```js
// postcss.confing.js
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js"), // name your custom tailwind
    ...
  ],
};
```

```js
// postcss.confing.js
module.exports = {
  "plugins": [
    require('tailwindcss')('tailwind.config.js'), // name your custom tailwind
    require('autoprefixer')(),
  ]
}
```

In both cases it solved the problem for me, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score -3):

You have to install tailwindcss with **vue-tailwind**.

Run `npm install tailwindcss`.

For more information, you can go here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite